# OpenXLS: how to set the Font of a Chart?

Tags: openxls

I'm using Java and OpenXLS to write out an Excel spreadsheet. I want to set the font of a chart. I used the setFontChart() method but it does not work. Can anybody help me, please? :)

Comment: Is there any code that you can provide us?

Comment: I create a chartHandle named ch and I add into it many dataseries. After I want to change his font like this.  
ch.setChartFont("Arial", "180"); but it doesn't work.